Bitbucket pipeline failing to build .NET 4.8 projects
I have been struggling for weeks to figure out how to get a pipeline running for our Bitbucket repo. Our application was designed in Visual Studio 2019 with .NET 4.8.
When I try using the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 image, the pipeline tries to build but then I get the following error message:

error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

However, I have downloaded and installed the Developer Pack to my PC but this doesn't seem to get the pipeline to recognize that it is there. (I am new to pipelines, so please let me know if I am missing a step there).
Alternatively, I have tried using the images
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8 and mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8
but get the errors:

rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8": no match for platform in manifest: not found

and

failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown.

Does anyone have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong here?

If you're trying to use the "standard" version of Pipelines, then it won't work - Pipelines only supports .NET Core/.NET Standard and .NET5 upwards. You can self-host Pipelines if you need .NET Framework runners: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-runners-for-windows/

Oh thank you @TiesonT. , I was not aware of that!

It's not documented all that well, but as far as I can recall, Bitbucket runs on some flavor of Unix, so .NET Framework is a no-go (ignoring Mono). Just as an FYI, I believe this links to relevant information on self-hosting the runner(s): https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-13452
